# Express mp4 video streaming making the video streaming-friendly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, video-streaming

I have to stream some mp4 videos, but from the browser for big videos it takes a lot to load even if I put preload="metadata". And I looked it up to see what was going, and everybody say that this problem is most likely caused by the fact that the videos I want to stream have the metadata somewhere in the end. So I came across the fluent-ffmpeg nodejs package that should do the trick, I tried it but i doesn't seem to work.

The code is this:

```
const headers = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${response.start}-${response.end}/${response.size}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": response.end - response.start + 1,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
};
res.writeHead(StatusCodes.PARTIAL_CONTENT, headers);

ffmpeg(videoStream)
  .format("mp4")
  .on("error", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
     console.log("an error happened: " + err.message);
  })
  .pipe(res, { end: true });
```

but it gives me this error : "an error happened: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: End of file"

what am I doing wrong?
Moreover if this is not the solution, what could I do to solve my issue?
Thanks a lot, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Properly streaming video means that you look at the `range` [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) on the incoming request and you send the client ONLY the byte range that it asked for - not the entire video all at once.  Read all about how to properly use the Range header to learn how to do this.  Doing this correctly with all browsers (yeah, I'm looking at you Apple) can sometime be tricky because if anything goes wrong, then the incremental streaming doesn't work and the browser falls back to downloading the entire video.

Comment: I already manage the range bytes, is not about that, the problem is that the browser even if i set preload="metadata" sends like 6 or 8 request with code 206 and each one gets around 1 mb of data, so is slow.

Comment: If I tell the video to load only the metadata why does it takes so much?

Comment: The code you show does NOT show managing incoming range requests.

Comment: What does "tell the video to load only the metadata" mean?  It is the server's job to respond the what the client is asking for, not the other way around.

Comment: Trust me it does, it is just done in a section of code I don't want to show you, but there is moreover you see that I set the headers accordingly. The first thing that the browser does is to ask for the metadata in order to gain info about the video like duration etc.., but for some reason it takes a lot ref about preload attribute : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp

Comment: Of course my code responds what the client is asking for, but the client is asking for a lot of request before allowing the user to play the video, and this results in a waiting of like 6 seconds which is a lot. The heavier the video is the longer I have to wait to be able to start it.

Comment: Yes, and that's probably because you're not providing the right type of responses from your server so that the client then understands it can use Range requests.  Can't really help you if you're not going to show the ACTUAL code for the entire request handler.